# If my function doesn't work on every object, how do I skip those objects?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to write a function and apply it to a list. Inside my function is a function written by some one else. If I make my list very easy, everything will work fine. But if I use all the real data I have, there are some bad objects and the outside function doesn't work and my whole function won't go through.

**What do I type to say "If the outside function doesn't work, skip that object and move to the next one in the list."?**  With or without NA, doesn't matter.

I cannot figure out how to write a reproducible example that would result in a list of dataframes, which is what happens inside this function. I'm willing to take any help to improve this question.

My function is something like this:

```
do_this<- function(x){
  outside_function(x))%>%  #this returns a dataframe for each object
  filter()%>%
  select()%>%
  summarise_each(funs(mean(., na.rm = TRUE))) #by the end the df is down to one row
}
```

This is how I apply the function to the list to come up with my final dataframe.

```
df<-bind_rows(lapply(my_list, do_this))
```

Comment: Look at the help for `try` or `tryCatch` maybe.

Comment: Does `outside_function` result in an error? Or return `NA`?

Comment: `outside_function` results in an error when it encounters an `x` it doesn't like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example:

```
myfun <- function(x) {if (x == 1) {stop("bad")} else x}
```

throws error on input of `1`:

```
lapply(1:4, myfun)  # stops from error
```

Just wrap it in try (as long as you don't need more complex error handling):

```
L <- lapply(1:4, function(x) try(myfun(x)))
```

And then you can use `Filter` to get rid of the "bad" cases:

```
Filter(function(x) !inherits(x, "try-error"), L)
```

Although you may want to just make your wrapper function more robust, or return `NULL` (or some other appropriate value) under the condition that makes the inner function fail.

Comment: I still get an error with the code you have here and when I try to incorporate this in my code, but it is helpful to think about working within `lapply` and not just my function.

Comment: Hmm, that's funny. Works fine for me. `try` prints the error message, but continues nonetheless. Are you sure you are not just seeing the printed error? The assignment to the object `L` should work. Without `try`, `L` would not exist after the failed function call.

Comment: You are right, I was just seeing the error message, but hadn't tried to print `L`.

Comment: It does! Took me a while to get through the last step of binding it all together, was hard to tell before that.